# Wrong total on measure with IIF

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx

I have a very simple set `[Sales Set]`:

```
{
  [Accounts Master].[Account Code].&[XXXXX1]
, [Accounts Master].[Account Code].&[XXXXX2] 
  ...
  [Accounts Master].[Account Code].&[XXXX20]
}
```

I ultimately want to create a calculated measure that will get its value from measure `Gross Sales` when the account is in this set or from an account group I have specified (let's call it Sample Account) and from `Net Sales` when it is not.

So far I have used the following measure `[Sales Measure]` to achieve that:

```
IIF
(
      Exists
      (
        [Sales Set]
       ,[Accounts Master].[Customer Description].CurrentMember
      ).Count
    = 1
  OR 
      Exists
      (
        [Accounts Master].[Account Group].&[Sample Account]
       ,[Accounts Master].[Customer Description].CurrentMember
      ).Count
    = 1
 ,[Measures].[Gross Sales]
 ,[Measures].[Net Sales]
)
```

This does what I want but the total disregards anything that is not in the `[Sales Set]` or in the Account Group `[Sample Account]`.

This is what happens:

```
        Account Group   **Sales Measure**   Gross Sales   Net Sales
           XXXXX1            **20**             20            12
           XXXXX2            **45**             45            35
           YYYYY1            **15**             25            15
           YYYYY2            **30**             40            30
          __________________________________________________________
Total                        **65**             130           92
```

Everything is as it should except the Total.

In this example the total for Sales Measure should be 110.

Is there a way that I can achieve the same functionality that I have now but also having the total being calculated correctly?

EDIT: On closer inspection the results are like these:

```
        Account Group   **Sales Measure**   Gross Sales   Net Sales
           XXXXX1            **20**             20            12
           XXXXX2            **45**             45            35
           YYYYY1            **15**             25            15
           YYYYY2            **30**             40            30
          __________________________________________________________
Total                        **130**             130           92
```

So it seems that the total of `Sales Measure` is always the same as the `Gross Sales` total.

Comment: is the client Excel?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, the client is Excel but the behavior is the same in BIDS cube browser as well.

Comment: is this SOLVE_ORDER related?

Comment: I have no prior experience with SOLVE_ORDER but I tried changing the calculated measure's solve order by moving it to the top, bottom and middle of the calculations pane in BIDS Cube Designer (which according to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145539.aspx should change its solve_order) with the same results as before.

Comment: ok - well at least that is crossed of the list!